# Why does "grep '.*[s]' file" work and "grep .*[s] file" doesn't?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, quoting

Comparing

> grep '.*[s]' file

with

> grep .*[s] file

Why do you need quotation marks to let this work properly? In the second case, grep seems trying to inspect every file with a period.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: you should always pass pattern to `grep` in single quotes unless you really knows what you are doing and why not to.

Comment: @jimmij Just single quotes? Why not double quotes?

Comment: @Hashim Because the content of single quotes are treated literally by the shell, but double quoted expressions are evaluated, e.g. variables are expanded.

Comment: @jimmij Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes (either single or double) around an argument inhibit glob expansion.

Your first example passes a Regular Expression as an argument to `grep`. Your second example contains a glob pattern which the shell itself expands, passing filenames that fit that pattern as arguments to `grep`.

Comment: So the glob pattern expands itself to all files in the current directory?

Comment: @JohnH.K.: Almost. It expands to all file names that begin with a dot `.` and end with an `s`. If you did `.*[Ss]` it would expand to file names that begin with a dot `.` and end with either `S` or `s`.

Comment: FWIW, when using globs I find it helpful to test them with `echo` or even better `printf "%s\n"` before plugging the glob into the actual command I want to run, just to make sure I haven't done something dumb. :)

Comment: A simple glob expands to match files in the current directory, but you can do things like `../*.txt` which will expand to the file names ending in `.txt` in the parent directory.

Answer (score 3):

Compare also:

```
echo '.*[s]' file
```

with

```
echo .*[s] file
```

This outputs the arguments as seen by the command.

In your first example you pass your `grep` command exactly two arguments: the pattern and the file.

In your second example your *shell* will handle the first argument and replace it with all the files starting with a dot and ending in "s". Therefore your grep command will get multiple arguments and it will try to find the first (expanded) filename in all other expanded filenames and the explicitly specified file.

Comment: Alternatively you can also use `set -x` to see all your commands as they are executed.